# Há alguma área aqui no SO-PT para pesquisas acadêmicas/cientificas?

Tags: novo-recurso, comunidade

Esta questão parece um tanto leviana, já que participo aqui a quase 1 ano, mas...

Estou atualmente, um tanto quando afastado, pois estou trabalhando em meu artigo final da Pós-Graduação e só venho até aqui "vez ou outra".

Então, estou atualmente submetendo uma pesquisa, para fundamentação de meu artigo e chegou a hora de enviar, para usuários "capacitados" em ajudar nessa pesquisa (Entendam "capacitados", como desenvolvedores, analistas ou afins e empresas de TI que trabalham com o tema abordado, no caso, Desenvolvimento para Dispositivos Moveis), então listando a quem enviar, pensei... "Onde estão os "capacitados" que conheço?", sim são poucos, pois essa é uma área não muito comum entre minha rede de contatos, então observando as tags: [android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), [ios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios), [windows-phone](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone), [phonegap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phonegap), [xamarin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin), por exemplo, que são relacionados ao meu artigo, já que trato do contraste entre Desenvolvimento Nativo X Desenvolvimento Hibrido. Percebi que poderia haver uma área aqui mesmo no SO-PT, para esse tipo de pesquisa relaciona as nossas áreas afins. E onde pudessemos, "tagear" as mesma para facilitar os voluntários. Já que onde posso encontra pessoas tão experientes e "capacitados" a uma pesquisa sobre este tema, do que no SO-PT? Talvez no [SOsão](https://stackoverflow.com/)? (mas teria que traduzir minha pesquisa).

- Então gostaria de saber se já existe, algo do gênero? (se houver me indiquem, pois uma boa pesquisa de amostragem teria que ser submetida a no minimo 100 entrevistados)
- E se há alguma possibilidade de isso poder ir como ideia para [SOsão](https://stackoverflow.com/), para quem sabe um dia ficar mais fácil cooperar com pesquisas cientificas de colegas, sendo mais uma forma de comunidade.

> Obs: <strike>Não postei o link para a pesquisa já que</strike>, não quero promover aqui nenhuma forma de promoção, e não permitir, outras aqui no meta baseado nesta ([Jurisprudência](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurisprud%C3%AAncia)).
>
> <sup>Mas se alguém for "capacitado" e se interessar em cooperar com minha pesquisa, me chama no chat que passo o link, com todo prazer.</sup>

Afinal "vai e vem" e voltamos a ser acadêmicos, então nada mais justo que pensar em uma forma de agregar valor ao site, para "nós" acadêmicos.

**Edit**

> Postei o link para a pesquisa nos comentários. Assim caso seja considerado inadequado. Posso remover sem deixar rastros.

Comment: Cara confesso que estou bem curioso e muito interessado em ajudar-te no que eu puder.

Comment: @emanuelsn, pois é, acho seria um ferramenta legal do StackOverflow aderir, com alguns critérios claro, talvez sendo disponível apenas a partir de determinada reputação.

Comment: Se entendi bem por mais que a intenção seja boa me parece ser um desvirtuamento da ferramenta. Da minha parte eu não acho que seria abusivo neste caso convidar aqui neste *post* as pessoas para participar da pesquisa. De fato não pode ser norma qualquer convite. Precisaria ser algo eventual e relevante para os membros da comunidade. Não acho que qualquer tipo de promoção deve ser considerada ruim. Se o interesse é geral, se não é algo para se **auto** promover, não vejo porque algo deve ser proibido. Mas não acho que dê para usar o *site* principal para a pesquisa em si.

Comment: @bigown, sim entendi, sua posição, talvez um pouco desvirtuado, mas se bem pensado e analisado, pode ser integrado ao SO, é que talvez mas a frente com mais tempo tento especificar melhor uma possível implementação, que acredito que seria viável. Mas pela possível aceitação da tema, 4 votos, até o momento, posso talvez postar o link a pesquisa aqui nos comentário, para os possíveis interessados em ajudar.

Comment: @emanuelsn, e os demais que tiverem interesse, estou postando o [link para a pesquisa](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1NH8dvdoJgcnG0A6hc1cvgh1t8UDCdCk_okUm6RMO1fw/viewform?usp=send_form). Se puderem, me ajudar, fico grato desde já. Obs: se isso for considerado inadequado, removo o comentário imediatamente.

Comment: Eu peguei o link da sua pesquisa dos comentários e ficarei muito feliz em ajudar. De todas as formas, o que eu penso sobre usar o SOPT para divulgar pesquisas eu colocarei em uma resposta. :)

Answer (score 9):

É claro que faz sentido pra você (e pra qualquer um com a sua necessidade) fazer a divulgação por aqui, pois afinal este é um local onde há bastante pessoas com o perfil que você precisa para os respondentes. Mas a ferramenta não foi feita pra isso. Ela existe para acumular perguntas e respostas com conhecimento potencialmente útil para mais pessoas *além de você*. Nesse ponto de vista, mesmo o Meta não tem esse propósito.

De fato, nós poderiamos permitir que esse tipo de pesquisa fosse feito aqui no Meta (porque aqui tem esse caráter menos formal na postagem de conteúdo), mas então - por consistência - não poderíamos impedir a divulgação de outras coisas que também são "justas" segundo o critério "nesse local tem muitas pessoas com o perfil desejado", como por exemplo:

- anúncios de vagas de emprego
- enquetes sobre linguagens preferidas
- promoções daquele compilador X ou daquele roteador Y
- e por ai vai...

Eu acho que você pode sim convocar a comunidade a te ajudar, e será muito bem-vindo para tal, mas deveria fazê-lo por meio do chat e não do meta (e principalmente não do site principal). Sei que a divulgação não tem o mesmo alcance, mas é o que me parece que pode ser útil sem potencialmente prejudicar a ideia original das ferramentas do StackExchange.

Comment: Concordo inteiramente com você, adaptar a ferramenta para isso desvirtuaria totalmente o seu propósito.

Comment: Perfeita observação!

Comment: Luiz, como comentei em minha resposta, para o @bigown, "é que tem os 2 lados da moeda, tava pensando somente em um deles (no caso minha necessidade)", o que você citou aqui, é muito valido e verdade, e como falei na pergunta, não quero abrir precedentes, para os exemplos que você citou. Mas ainda acho a discussão dessa ideia valida, no intuído, de achar um formato, que seja adequado para o mesmo.

Comment: Oi Fernando. A discussão de possíveis melhorias é sempre bem-vinda. Porém eu insisto que esta ferramenta não foi feita pra essa necessidade específica. Além dos problemas de "adaptar" o que existe que eu já mencionei, eu honestamente não acho que o custo (em termos de tempo, recursos, e até mesmo motivação) para construir algo para pesquisas seja justificável aos criadores do SE.

Comment: Sim, @LuizVieira, adaptar é problemático, mas não digo adaptação e sim agregação, a parte de ser dentro do SO, é que pesa. Mas desenvolver algo nesse sentido que seja separado, com integração, já vi que o SE, tem uma API, mas nunca tentei nada, então não sei até onde ela vai. O que penso é em uma ferramenta paralela. Na verdade, nem eu sei. =D. Hehe. Mas esse é um problema do mundo acadêmico, que nem é a realidade a todos aqui (mas acredito a maioria). Acho que estou adaptando o problema. Talvez tenha que pensar o inverso. Não trazer o problema para a solução e sim a solução para o problema.

Comment: Nesse caso, tenta postar no Metão (como o @bigown já te sugeriu) pra ver o que o pessoal de lá acha. Talvez se você sugerir isso como uma ferramenta de apoio adicional, tal qual o [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/), pode ser que vá pra frente. Eu acho que as suas chances não são boas, mas quem sabe eu estou errado (nesse caso em especial seria ótimo estar errado! hehe). Boa sorte! :)

Answer (score 4):

Vou postar aqui uma opção com uma serie de detalhes de como poderia ser implementado essa funcionalidade aqui na SO-PT, para poder ser votado e discutido pela comunidade.

**Opção 1:**

Se adicionaria uma opção na tela inicial para Acadêmico ou Pesquisas Ciêntificas, já que penso que não deveria ser outro site da rede, e sim parte do site, para compartilhar pesquisas cientificas para a cooperação de colegas da área, que são aptos a responder as pesquisas, então para isso criei algumas regras, seria assim:

1. Pesquisas só poderiam ser publicadas, por exemplo, por usuários com
   reputação maior ou igual a 1000;
2. As tags para pesquisas devem seguir as mesmas regras das tags das perguntas para do SO, sendo ligadas a tecnologia de desenvolvimento, que a pesquisa envolve, por exemplo;
3. Pesquisas só poderiam ser respondidas, por exemplo, por usuários com
   reputação maior ou igual a 500, e com alguma pergunta ou resposta contendo alguma das tags da pesquisa, com pontuação de 3 ou mais positivas. (ai está uma das importâncias, no meu ponto de vista, de ser parte do SO);
4. Cada pesquisa só poderia ser respondida uma vez por usuário;
5. E penso que a participação em pesquisas não deveria ser gratificado com nenhuma reputação, no máximo com medalhas ou nem isso. (Já que participar de pesquisas é um ato totalmente voluntário. (Apesar que responder uma questão aqui no SO e ajudar alguém também é, e é gratificado), mas o que quero dizer com isso é que não deve-se estimular pessoas a participar só pelo fato da gratificação);

Segue uma imagem (da minha imaginação) da opção na pagina inicial:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Edit**

Fui na Ferramenta de Desenvolvedor do navegador e adicionei o botão, segue a imagem, só tem um problema, não coube e quebrou o layout :(, mas resolvi "graduei o site" e tirei o **Beta**. É uma boa desculpa para graduar logo isso. Hehe.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> Também pensei em uma solução na linha de pensamento do @bigown, nos seus comentário a pergunta, mas especificamente [este](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2403/h%C3%A1-alguma-%C3%A1rea-aqui-no-so-pt-para-pesquisas-acad%C3%AAmicas-cientificas?noredirect=1#comment8084_2403), talvez criando uma tag aqui no Meta, assim [pesquisa-cientifica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pesquisa-cientifica), por exemplo. Mas como ligar com SO, com as tags de lá? Vou tentar amadurecer e postar aqui no futuro, ou se alguém tiver alguma ideia, compartilhe.

Comment: Eu não sou contra esta ideia. Claro que não exatamente da forma como você colocou. Eu acho que o site poderia de uma forma um pouco diferente ter espaço para outros formatos, inclusive das tão mal faladas listas, que não é muito diferente do que você propõe. Se a SE que sempre foi competente em achar boas soluções no passado se comprometer com isto, acho que seria uma boa adição ao *site* no formato correto. Mas eles já se mostraram arredios à qualquer tipo de ideia neste sentido. De qualquer forma no http://meta.stackexchange.com poderia receber mais atenção. Mas posso garantir que não boa.

Comment: "mas resolvi "graduei o site" e tirei o Beta" :D

Comment: @bigown, é que tem os 2 lados da moeda, tava pensando somente em um deles (no caso minha necessidade), mas mesmo assim, após ler outras opiniões como a sua e do Luiz Vieira. Ainda acho como você citou que, não é uma má ideia, mas também não é uma boa, pelo menos, não nesse meu simples e discreto formato, mas se for algo bem elaborado e estudado acho que poderia se tornar viável.